Duplicate entries when added to a list by a C# function
I'm trying to run a Monte Carlo Simulation by:

Randomly creating a list of items (12 properties) with about 5200 entries in list.
Process this list to return a single object called result (20 properties) via the function called ProcessResult.
Each result is then added to a different list, called listMC.

I repeat this process 2500 times but I noticed that results are duplicated within the list. It is usually 3 or 4 similar entries before getting a different one.
I managed to solve the issue by adding a pause in the process. Turns out that 12ms is the right time as I would still get 3 or 4 duplicated entries if using 10 or 11ms.
I tried to streamline the processResult function as much as possible and it goes through the whole list only once (it used to go through the list 4 times before) but I didn't see any improvement.
I'm wondering if this is normal behavior or if there was a better code to write to avoid having to implement the pause.
Here is the function:
    public static List<result> mcSimul(List<item> list, int numTrades)
    {
        List<result> listMC = new List<result>();

        //Create 2500 result 
        for (int i =0; i<2500; i++)
        {
            List<item> randomList = new List<item>();
            Random random = new Random();

            //Create random list of items 
            for (int j=0; j<list.Count(); j++)
            {
                int k = random.Next(list.Count());  //==>the list created contains the same number of items as the input list)
                randomList.Add(list[k]);
            }

            //Process randomly created list of trades
            result resultTmp = processResult(randomList);

            listMC.Add(resultTmp); //==> DUPLICATED RESULTS
            
            Thread.Sleep(12); //==> If I don't put this, same resultTmp are added to the list
        }
        return listMC;
}


What is an item/result and what happens in processResult.

An item is an object with 12 properties
processResult runs calculations using some of these properties and return an object (result) with 20 properties

No show the code. Are you doing some kind of multi-threading or something? Also why are you recreating Random every loop?

On older .net frameworks Random is seeded from the system clock, which on windows only updates to a new value approximately every 16 ms. If you make a new Random inside a fast running loop it will get the same seed value and churn out the same "random" integer several times in a row, until the clock changes. Don't make a new Random all the time, make it once eg as a class level variable and use it repeatedly
